# Can anybody use Leaks? (from Instruments)

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

I've written a simple program in C and objC with a leak, and I cannot understand `Leaks`.
here it is:

`int main(void)
{
     int t = 78;
     t = malloc(50);
     t = 4;
     return 0;
}`

Can it show me which variable is the leak, or where it leaks?

Every `Leaks` tutorial on the internet (all two of them) are bad.

please help?

Comment: Perhaps you can show us the code that has the leak.

Answer (score 3):

If you are testing the Leaks instrument with the code you provided, it is no wonder that it can't uncover any problems.

- Leaks has a default snapshot interval of 10 seconds. But your program won't even run for 10s.
- You are allocating in the scope of the application's entry point. "t" is valid (when not freed) until main exits. So the OS would reclaim the memory anyway.
- And foremost: Your code does not contain a leak. It would be a leak if you "loose reference" to t. (e.g. by doing another t = malloc() or assigning t some other variable)

If you want to see Leaks in action, create a default Cocoa Application, add an instance variable "test" to your AppDelegate and put the following code into the implementation.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
   test = malloc(50);
   test = malloc(20);
}
```

Comment: Did you declare "test" in the header file?  Which version of Xcode/Instruments are you using? I just double checked the code I posted above and it clearly shows 1 leak occurring at line with the 2nd malloc.

Comment: indeed yours works. but how do I see where in the code is the leak?

Comment: View → Extended Detail. This shows you the call stack that leads to the leak.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used Leaks, but there are plenty of tutorials on the net, starting with Apple's - [Apple's developer documentation on the subject](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingLeaks.html), [Mobile Orchard](http://mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/) and [Cocoa is my Girlfriend](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/02/cocoa-tutorial-fixing-memory-leaks-with-instruments/), which seems to be the best.

Comment: I will try again.. I have seen all these, but I still can't use it. Is it just me?

Comment: Maybe! If you are using XCode 4, then the static analysis can be quite good at spotting potential leaks, you could try that.

Comment: I use the static analysis, but it goes so far. if I add a printf with t inside it, then analysis is shows nothing.